# Alternating row colors with some rows hidden

Tags: jquery, html-table

3rd attempt. I have a table pulled from a remote server and I hid some rows using `$('tr:nth-child(row#)').hide();`. Now the table row colors do not alternate. Also, table cells change color depending on what is in the cell. If a cell value is 81-100% it's green, at 61-80% it's orange, and at 0-60% it's red. Here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr:even').addClass('even'); $('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
});

var $trs = $('tr').removeClass('even odd').filter(":visible");
$trs.filter(':even').addClass('even');
$trs.filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
```

Here's my CSS: `tr.odd td{ background-color: #FFFFFF;} tr.even td{background-color: #C0C0C0;}`

The above codes actually alternate the rows, but it removes the colors of the cells. Whereas `tr.odd{ background-color: #FFFFFF;} tr.even{background-color: #C0C0C0;}` retains the colors of the cells but removes the alternating colors. Please help.

Here's my entire HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
        <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript"> 
        function View(){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;        

                $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R1';}).text('Row1'); //white
                $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R2';}).text('Row2'); //grey
                $('tr:nth-child(3)').hide();                                            //white
                $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R4';}).text('Row4'); //grey
                $('tr:nth-child(5)').hide();                                            //white
                $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R6';}).text('Row6'); //grey
                $("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R7';}).text('Row7'); //white

                // Alternate visible rows to white and grey
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('tr:even').addClass('even');
                    $('tr:odd').addClass('odd');
                });

                var $trs = $('tr').removeClass('even odd').filter(":visible");
                $trs.filter(':even').addClass('even');
                $trs.filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
            }
        }
        var parameters = "search="+"rog_en_vo_ts_t1";
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://process_this_table.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(parameters);         
    }
    </script>
    </head>

<body onload="View();" >
    <div id="datatable" align="center"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
tr.odd{background-color: #FFFFFF;} 
tr.even{background-color: #C0C0C0;}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle, please?

Comment: Here you go jsfiddle.net/nTtyd.

Comment: Your fiddle does not work, your ajax call is a local address too - so we can't see the data you're pulling back

Comment: Hi user887515. Not sure how to use fiddle. Please ask anything relating my code and I'll explain. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to simulate ajax calls either so we'll skip that. How are you setting the colours based on the cell value I don't see that in the fiddle.

Comment: The cell colours are not in my control because the table is being pulled from a server. But viewing the source code here's what I got `<script src="someremoteserver/sorttable.js"></script> <style type = "text/css">'; td.datacellone{ background-color: #C0C0C0; } th.datacellheader{ background-color: #6A5ACD; } td.alert{ background-color: #FF0000; } td.orange{ background-color: #FFA500; } td.green{ background-color: #008000; } </style> </script>`. I updated my original post. Have a look at my html and css.

Comment: Please put the final table you receive after AJAX call on your server to the jsfiddle. That way; we can "actually" work on problem at hand.

Comment: "table cells change color depending on what is in the cell. If a cell value is 81-100% it's green, at 61-80% it's orange, and at 0-60% it's red"...where is this code?

Comment: Hi hjpotter92. I'm sorry. Not sure what you mean. Please dumb it down for me. Basically, the final table has alternating rows but since I hid some rows it's no longer alternating grey and white. Also there are colored cells and if I do this `tr.odd td{background-color: #FFFFFF;} ` they're overridden by grey and white, but ``tr.odd{background-color: #FFFFFF;}` retains the colored cells but no alternating grey and white rows.

Comment: Hi Matt. That code is probably in the php on the remote server `xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://process_this_table.php", true);`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

Click a row to remove it. The alternating colours are kept and cells show accordingly based upon their value.

The key for your alternating rows is to ask for visible before odd or even.

http://jsfiddle.net/WWFUr/

```
function setRowColours(){
    $('table tr:visible:odd').css({"background": "grey"});
    $('table tr:visible:even').css({"background": "lightgrey"});
    $('td.percentage').each(function(){
        if($(this).html() > 80){
            $(this).css({"background": "green"});
        } else if($(this).html() <= 60){
            $(this).css({"background": "red"});
        } else{
            $(this).css({"background": "orange"});            
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setRowColours();
});

$('tr').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    setRowColours(); 
});
```

Comment: This works! But let me explain further. Only 1 column has that condition. That column is called "ROI". The other columns have different conditions. For example, another column named "Debt Owed" cannot show a red cell if the value is 0. So how do I code this so that it's based on a column header name instead of a TD class since I don't know the specifics of this table I am accessing remotely. Thank you.

Comment: You would have to find out the column number of the Debt Owed column and then apply to the nth-child('number of the debt owed column') of the tr. You should probably ask that as a new question, as the question you asked here was about alternating row colours.

Comment: I think i got it. I replaced `$('td.percentage').` with `$("th").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Debt Owed';}).` and the condition was specific to that column only. user887515, thank you so much! You will be blessed my friend.

Comment: Sorry wait, the rows are not alternating white and grey. I need help still.

Comment: They do alternate. I didn't choose white and grey, rather light grey and grey, but they do alternate. Tested in latest Chrome, FF and IE8, 9 and 10. You may have issues with the latest jQuery with jsfiddle in IE10, switch to a previous version and its fine. http://jsfiddle.net/WWFUr/1/

Comment: user887515, you're right. Everything works now. I swear this time lol.